# knitr, error = TRUE with external R script

Tags: r, knitr

I'm new to knitr, but I've been doing a lot of reading on it and have looked around for a solution to this problem here and other places. So far, I haven't been able to find an answer. I'm using R version 3.1.1 and R studio .98953.

I'm trying to show a reader an expected error message in a beamer slide with knitr. If I had included the chunk in a .Rnw file, I could get the result by setting `ERROR = TRUE` in the chunk option. However, I can't get that to work when the .Rnw is referencing an external R script. I just get an error message in the console and it refuses to print. The only way to get it to print is to comment out the offending code in the script, but then I don't get the error message. Any suggestion?

Edit: Here is the .R script.

```
---- demo ----
TRUE <- 7          # Unlike T, TRUE cannot be overridden
```

and here is the global chunk in the .Rnw

```
<<r setup, echo=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath('../'))
@

<<chunk options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
     options(replace.assign = TRUE, width = 50)
     knit_hooks$set(par = function(before, options, envir) {
         if (before)
             par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.1, 0.1), cex.lab = .95, cex.axis = 0.9, mgp = c(2, 0.7, 0), tcl = -0.3)
     })
    read_chunk("scripts/r-syntax.R")
    opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "../figure/rsyntax", cache.path = "../cache/rsyntax", dev = "tikz" , cache = TRUE, fig.align = "center", par= TRUE)
@
```

(I've modified this code from another example, which might have been a mistake, as I'm still figuring out what it all means).

There is obviously a problem with opts_chunk$set part. If I comment it out, it works fine.

(I didn't run into a problem with the other chunks, by the way).

Edit 2:

The problem is with the `cache = TRUE` option. Changing it to read `cache = FALSE` solves the problem.

Comment: A reproducible example, please.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm new here, and I should have included an example earlier. There must be a problem with some of the other chunk options I have. When I commented out everything but the read_chunk function, it worked fine. I added the original chunk above, and I'll investigate on my own at a later date, but I won't have time for a bit. As soon as I figure out where the problem lies, I'll add it.

Comment: As I write above, the problem is with the cache = TRUE option. Changing it to cache = FALSE allows it to print.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) has warned you:

> [...] It is extremely important to note that usually a chunk that has side-effects should *not* be cached.